# Help on validation code algorithm

Tags: algorithm-design

I wonder if someone can help me find the algorithm used to generate validation codes from a serial number.

I already have some working examples of serials->codes pairs:

19003148 -> 523254

19003162 -> 458091

19003064 -> 618138

20000589 -> 138224

I understand that the validation code is somehow calculated directly from S/N digits, but i can't find the equation.

Any help welcome!

Comment: If this is meant to be a code to verify that the serial number is in the user's possession, it might not be an algorithm at all but instead a random number saved in a database somewhere alongside the serial number. It's impossible to tell without more detail.

Comment: No, there is no database, It's a  standalone cash register machine and i'm almost 100% sure that code is calculated from serial number digits.

Comment: It's something directly related to serial number and is not checked against a database. Many years ago i had the same case and i figured out the equation (i had to add the first 2 digits + 2 last digits and then multiply by 102) but now i can't find out the logic.

Comment: @NikosGiannoulis: If you are sure there was such linear dependency, then just write a script that checks possible cases. It if is linear, then there are not sufficient pairs to solve it in a *single* iteration. That's why there will be *multiple* iterations needed to check each case.